# I lost my R file.?I don't know what happened.?

Tags: java, android, r.java-file, buildconfiguration

I was working on my android project. After completing some coding, I imported remaining classes by pressing `ctrl+shift+o`. Than I cleaned my project. After cleaning the project I lost my `BuildConfig.java` file.
How can i get it back?
I think that R.java is now renamed as BuildConfig.java.(For all developers)
Am i right?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please don't tag this question with [tag:r], the tag about the R-project for statistical computing. I have removed this tag.

Comment: @Andrie: rather than only remove the `[r]` tag, please replace it with the `[r.java-file]` tag.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Thank you.  I bow to the master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you haven't imported an foreign `R` file. Occasionally, `CTRL+SHIFT+O` will import `android.R` which will mess up your project. Delete the import statement, clean and build your project again.

Comment: Note: copy-pasting code between projects will cause Eclipse to add an import statement without prompting or notification.

Comment: I closed eclipse at night and when i see at morning R file was automatically generated.May be it was because of virus in my PC.

Answer (score 1):

You should have an BuildConfig.java and an R.java in your gen folder (inside your package).

If the R.java isn't generated after cleaning, make sure that you don't have any errors in your layouts. (An layout error will cause the R to be removed and not to come back before a clean :) )

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project 2-3 times. It will work.

Comment: 2-3 times? What an idea sirji !!